# SELECT as is_boolean in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In snowflake/SQL you can do something like:

```
SELECT my_col = 'yes' as is_my_col FROM my_table
```

This will select it as a bool value, how can I do this in pyspark if I have a df?

Such as `my_df`

`my_df.select(??.cast('bool'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_df.select((F.col('my_col') == 'yes').alias('is_my_col'))
```